# jqGrid.getLocalRow(rowId) and jqGrid.getRowData(rowId) return different rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using a jqgrid with local data.
For example, when selecting a row, I do the following treatment:

```
onSelectRow : function (rowId) {
   var localRow = $grid_selector.getLocalRow(rowId);
   var rowData = $grid_selector.getRowData(rowId);

   console.log(localRow.customer_id == rowData.customer_id)   
}
```

The expected output was `true`, but I got `false`. Does anyone know why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

See this...  [jqGrid Methods](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)

> **getLocalRow**
>
> Return the row data from the local array stored in data parameter when the datatype is local
>
> **getRowData**
>
> Returns an array with data of the requested id = rowid. The returned array is of type name:value, where the name is a name from colModel and the value from the associated column in that row. It returns an empty array if the rowid can not be found.
>   1. Do not use this method when you are editing the row or cell. This will return the cell content and not the actuall value of the input element.2.the performance of this method becomes an issue. Do not use this method in the body of “for” and “when”. (When calling this method, it will calculates the row datas one time.)
>   If the rowid is not set the method return all the data from the grid in array

Hence getRowData returning an array so you should check like below

```
console.log(localRow.customer_id == rowData[0].customer_id)
```

Comment: The two methods are not returning arrays. Both rowData.customer_id and localRow.customer_id are numeric values and valid customer_id's in the data array.